# Flutter scaledown font based on container size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to scaledown font based on container height and width. Tried using Fittedbox it's not working with multiline text.

```
SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: Text(
                widget.model.poem,
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

It's shrinking the font as small as shown below. Tried using "Flexible" too not working.

[image]

Comment: There are multiple questions for this issue unresolved issue and most of them come to the same conclusion using auto_size_text package

Answer (score 1):

There ain't many ways to walk around with this issue.

**Use `auto_size_text` plugin**

If you wanna automatically resize fonts based on parent widget's width and height, using [`auto_size_text`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package is the best option. It's really easy to use and has rich documentation.

Sample Usage:

```
AutoSizeText(
  'The text to display',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  maxLines: 2,
)
```

**Have fun!**